# Given a trajectory and a target, can I work out how much to scale the velocity by in order to hit a target?

Tags: c#, math

For example, let's say the landing point of a projectile is 9m away from the launch position, but we want it to land 10m away. Can I work out how much the launch velocity needs to be scaled by in order to travel 1m extra?

Comment: I suggest reading this short document: [Projectile Motion (pdf)](http://www-personal.umd.umich.edu/~jameshet/IntroLabs/IntroLabDocuments/150-03%20Projectile%20Motion/Projectile%20Motion%207.0.pdf). The answer you seek should be around page 7, but you need to read from the beginning to understand.

Comment: Also, this question is more about physics as it is about c#. It has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: Fair enough @TobiasBrösamle. It's a problem I encountered while programming, so I just tagged it with c# without much thought. But you're absolutely right, especially seeing as I asked the question in very general terms!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it's a math problem. The distance `L` can be computed (`10` meters is a *short* distance, the velocity is small and we can assume *air friction* being negligible) as

```
 L = v^2 * sin (2 * fi) / g
```

where

```
 v  - initial speed
 fi - angle
 g  - acceleration
```

if we use `k = sin (2 * fi) / g` assuming that both angle and acceleration are constant, we'll have

```
 L     = k * v^2
 L + 1 = k * (v * scale)^2
```

And

```
 scale = sqrt((L + 1) / L)
```

In your case

```
 scale = sqrt(10 / 9) ~ 1.0541
```

So the velocity should be increased by `5.4%`

**Edit:** If you want to change horizontal component only, note that

```
 t = 2 * Vvert / g
 L = Vhorz * t
```

Since `Vvert` and acceleration are constant, `t` is constant as well. So you have

```
 L     = Vhorz * t
 L + 1 = Vhorz * scale * t
```

This can easily be solved as

```
 scale = (L + 1) / L
```

In your case

```
 scale = 10 / 9 ~ 1.1111
```

If you want to increase *horizontal* component only you should increase it by `11%`

Comment: Thank you - this is brilliant. Can I do something similar if I want to adjust only the horizontal velocity, leaving the vertical velocity untouched?

Comment: @yeahads: sure, in this case you change *angle* `fi`, note that `tan(fi) = vertical / horizontal`